# Need to find Secure Websocket Broker for MQTT

Tags: javascript, https, websocket, mqtt, mosquitto

Is there a test broker that supports secure websockets for MQTT ? ( wss:// )
Can anyone point out the right resources if available ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mosquitto should support Secure Websockets.

And example of the configuration can be found here:

http://jpmens.net/2014/07/03/the-mosquitto-mqtt-broker-gets-websockets-support/

Comment: Thanks ! This is what I was looking for.